# How do I transfer specific attributes from a point feature class to a polyline feature class

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, data-transfer

I have a point feature class that I have used to create stream segments of interest. Now I'm trying to transfer some of the attributes from the points feature class to the new polyline feature class. Transferring all of the attributes would be ok, but I'm not interested in all of them. I've tried the Attribute Transfer Mapping function under the Spatial Adjustment Toolbar and think that's what I need but have evidently not been feeding the tool the right info. I'm using ArcMap 10.0. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at performing a [Spatial Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000q000000)?

Answer (score 2):

I think @Polygeo is right on in recommending the [Spatial Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000q000000).  Keep in mind that you can set the search radius so that lines within a search radius of your points will be incorporated into the spatial join.  I would like to add that you may need to also use [Split Line at Vertices (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003z000000) if your polyline is multipart (i.e. multiple segments have one attribute).  You may also want to refer to the [An overview of the Overlay toolset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000009000000) from ArcGIS help to learn about the various overlay methods that may better meet your needs.